# Trying to Output from MySQL in PHP to Divs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect page management up to our database, so on the manage pages page, it needs to list all pages from the database, one on each row - for as many pages as there are (well, until I figure out how to add pagination - but one step at a time)!

Page is all connected to database.

This is what I have.

```
$query_all_pages = "SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE parent_id = '0'";
$all_pages = mysql_query($query_all_pages, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row_all_pages = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_pages);
$num_rows_all_pages = mysql_num_rows($all_pages);
```

The table which this data needs to be outputted to is made up of divs, see below:

```
<div class="table_row"> 
<div class="td_page_name"><p><?php echo $row_all_pages['page_display_name']; ?></p></div>   
<div class="td_page_title"><p>Title Here...</p></div>
<div class="td_page_type"><p>Type...</p></div>
<div class="td_page_view"><p>View</p></div>
<div class="td_page_edit"><p>Edit</p></div>
<div class="td_page_delete"><p>Delete</p></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've been attempting to display the list of pages in the appropriate column, but after an hour of messing around with various variations, I've got to admit, I don't really know what I'm doing here.

I'm not sure if I need to be inserting a while loop in PHP but if anyone could explain how I should be calling in the results into the appropriate column as per the above variables, I will be eternally grateful.

Any help, greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$dbRows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_pages)) {
    $dbRows[] = $row;
}


Then once you have all the data just do this

<?php foreach($dbRows as $row) { ?>
    <div class="table_row"> 
        <div class="table_page_name"><p><?php echo $row['page_display_name']; ?></p></div>   
        <div class="table_title"><p><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></p></div>
        <div class="table_type"><p><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></p></div>
        <div class="table_view"><p><?php echo $row["view"]; ?></p></div>
        <div class="table_edit"><p><?php echo $row["edit"]; ?></p></div>
        <div class="table_delete"><p><?php echo $row["delete"]; ?></p></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer, I tried your suggestion (noticing the typo $dbRow instead of $dbRows) and it has now listed a row per page, but it is the same page listed. I'm thinking that this line needs amending? <div class="td_page_name"><p><?php echo $row_all_pages['page_display_name']; ?></p></div> Many thanks.

Comment: yeah that would changed to `row['page_display_name'];`  I do not know all the names and what you would require, but you are just needing how to get every row.  Since you are using a functional approach either mine or @ErmSo would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE parent_id = '0'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1) {
        echo "No results";
    }
    else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<div class="table_row"> 
<div class="td_page_name"><p><?php echo $row['page_display_name']; ?></p></div>   
<div class="td_page_title"><p>Title Here...</p></div>
<div class="td_page_type"><p>Type...</p></div>
<div class="td_page_view"><p>View</p></div>
<div class="td_page_edit"><p>Edit</p></div>
<div class="td_page_delete"><p>Delete</p></div>
</div>

        <?php }
    }
?>
```

Try using the mysql_fetch_array function

Additional:

If you wanted to check the length of your data (as you mentioned), you could write a custom function like so:

```
<?php
function checkLength($str) {
   if(strlen($str)<10) {
       return $str;
   }
   else {
       return substr($str,0,10);
   }
}
?>
```

And then in your existing code, call the checkLength() function like so:

```
<?php echo checkLength($row['page_display_name']); ?>
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi ErmSo, thanks for your suggestion. I've implemented it, and this has listed all the pages. Excellent, thanks very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. I would also suggest using a table inside "<div class='table_row"..", you'd get the same design with a bit of CSS work but it would be easier to manage - plus if you had a lot of results, pages with many divs can take a while to load.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will consider converting the div content to tables. It has completely screwed the design of the table now infact (heh). I'm trying to cut off text if it is over a certain amount of characters using <?php echo $row['page_display_name']; if (strlen($row['page_display_name']) > 12) {echo '...';}; ?> but it doesn't seem to be working - please could you advise, whether I need to be adding something else? Many thanks for your help.